# Why are CQ/AEM workflow being synchronous

Tags: workflow, aem

I created a workflow where I need each process step to be asynchronous.

For example, 1st step is create thumbnails in different size that I need.  After creating those thumbnails, then I would use those thumbnail to create a folio and package the contents and publish it.  This is the reason the thumbnail must be created first.

Another thing I need to do is starting another workflow and I need to wait for that workflow to finish before it goes to another step.  How can this be done?

It seems all steps are starting together at the same time and not being executed after one another.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9EsPOTK.png]

Comment: I think the wording synchronous and asynchronous are used wrong in this context. Parallel or seqeuntial would be more fitting. If you have one single workflow without forks, then the individual steps are sequential and I don't see why they would be executed in parallel. This would only happen, if you have multiple independant workflows triggered at the same time. Can you maybe post a screenshot of your workflow to help better understand?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Screenshot link added:  http://i.imgur.com/9EsPOTK.png

Comment: This looks ok to me. I assume the Create and Publish Folio are custom Workflow steps? Maybe you don't select the correct rendition in these steps and are always working with the original.